# What does it mean in node.js by http.ClientRequest implements an interface?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading [the documentation for http.ClientRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) and it says... "The request implements the Writable Stream interface. This is an EventEmitter." What does this mean? Does it mean that http.ClientRequest gets all of the methods and events that both Writable Stream and EventEmitter get and the arguments it will accept are the same as EventEmitter (event, listener)?

If this is correct, then how is it that in the [example code for http.request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)... within the callback function of http.request there is a line that says res.on('data', ...)? The documentation says that this res parameter implements http.ClientRequest, but when I checked, the 'data' event is listed for stream.Readable but not stream.Writable.

Here is the example code from the url:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: it implements both: writable outside the callback, readable inside the callback...

Comment: Worth noting that streams are implemented on top of event emitters. In other words, every stream in Node is also an event emitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is YES, according the http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream , 
    All streams are instances of EventEmitter.

About the second question,

> The documentation says that this res parameter implements http.ClientRequest,

Nope. The returned object(that's `req`) is an instance of the ClientRequest which implements writable stream, in the sample code the `data` event is bound to `res` which is readable stream. The [doc](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) said:

```
http.request() returns an instance of the http.ClientRequest class.
```

Don't confuse the `request` with `response`. :)